# Creating dataframe from numpy arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, where each row describe a matrix (3,3):

[image]

I transformed this dataframe in multiple matrices, to do some matrices operations with them. I used the code:

```
df.to_numpy().reshape(-1,3,3)
```

Which returned:

[image]

This is exactly what I wanted but, after finished the operations with the matrices, I need to transform all of these matrices in the original form of the dataframe, like in the first image. How can I do this?
There's some analogue function to `.to_numpy()`? I tried  `pd.DataFrame(array)` but don't worked.

```
d = pd.DataFrame(array)
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
array_2d = array.reshape((-1, 9))
d = pd.DataFrame(array_2d)
```